# Which DNA polymerase can use a nick as priming site?

Tags: dna, polymerase

Which DNA polymerase (commercially available) can initiate polymerization at nicks, without a standard primer?

My goal is to perform rolling circle amplification starting at a nick.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a DNA polymerase that can perform [nick translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nick_translation). NEB maintains a [chart](https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/selection-charts/dna-polymerase-selection-chart) listing the properties of their polymerases, including *nick translation* and *extension from nick*.  Without additional details, it looks like *Taq* would work for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for something with strand displacement activity rather than 5’ removal. My goal is to perform rolling circle amplification starting at a nicking site.